# Kubernetes Port Forwarding - Error listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:88: bind: permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding, minikube

I am using minikube on my local machine. Getting this error while using kubernetes port forwarding. Can anyone help?

```
mjafary$ kubectl port-forward  sa-frontend 88:80

Unable to listen on port 88: All listeners failed to create with the following errors: 
Unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:88: bind: permission denied, Unable to create listener: Error listen tcp6 [::1]:88: bind: permission denied
error: Unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{88 80}]
```

Comment: This may be due to the port running locally and conflicting with this port forward

Comment: works after finding processes with netstat and killing the process with kill -9 command!

Answer (score 56):

`kubectl` fails to open the port 88 because it is a privileged port. All ports <1024 require special permissions.

There are many ways to solve your problem.

- You can stick to ports >= 1024, and use for example the port 8888 instead of 88: `kubectl port-forward sa-frontend 8888:80`
- You could use `kubectl` as root: `sudo kubectl port-forward sa-frontend 88:80` (not recommended, kubectl would then look for its config as root)
- You could grant the `kubectl` binary the capability to open privileged ports. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/892391/48678) explains in depth how to do this.

If you want to go for the 3rd option, here is a short way of doing it:

```
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/bin/kubectl
```

This will let `kubectl` open any port while still running with the privileges of a regular user. You can check if this worked by using

```
sudo getcap /usr/bin/kubectl 
/usr/bin/kubectl = cap_net_bind_service+eip
```

Be aware that this grants the permission to whoever uses the binary. If you want finer grained permissions, use authbind.

Note: as [ng-sek-long](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6463291/ng-sek-long) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775328/kubernetes-port-forwarding-error-listen-tcp4-127-0-0-188-bind-permission-de/55023272?noredirect=1#comment122743640_55023272), `kubectl` is not necessarily installed as `/usr/bin/kubectl`. You should replace it with the path to the kubectl binary on your machine.

Comment: Just to add a note that `/usr/bin/kubectl` might not always be the correct path (e.g. mine is installed on `/usr/local/bin/kubectl`), use a quick `whereis kubectl` will be able to identify your kubectl binary location, cheers

Answer (score 8):

[As mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55023272/712334) by user48678 you can bypass the limitation using `sudo`.

Add `-E` flag to pass environment.

```sh
mjafary$ sudo -E kubectl port-forward  sa-frontend 88:80
```

If you don't pass `-E`, the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable will not be set for example.

Answer (score 2):

I tried sudo as follows and it got me past the permission denied issue. 
sudo kubectl port-forward sa-frontend 88:80

I am now getting a different issue but will create a new tracker for that to keep things straight

Answer (score 1):

You can receive the permission denied error when port forwarding with kubectl if the target port on the local host is already in use.

Ensure that you do not have a docker container or another application running on port 88.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use other port to redirect

```
sudo -E kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 nginx-yaml 9000:80
```

and access : http://localhost:9000

Answer (score -3):

Probably your localhost - the local machine is using ipv6 when ipv4 is expected.

> Error listen **tcp4** 127.0.0.1:88: bind: permission denied, Unable to
>   create listener: Error listen **tcp6** [::1]:88: bind: permission
>   denied

Please disable IPv6.

Can you show the output of?:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with ipv6.